# Exact location of Agya chakra

Tags: body, agya-chakra

Generally, everyone says the location of [Agya chakra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajna) is between the eyebrows at the forehead.

Is agya chakra really located *at* the forehead or is it located *inside* the forehead?

Let's take the forehead along with eyebrows as a vertical plane and both eyebrows, both ears and the back of the head as a horizontal plane.

If Agya chakra is at the forehead then it lies in the vertical plane.
If Agya chakra is inside the forehead then it lies in the horizontal plan

Agya chakra is associated with [pineal gland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pineal_gland) and that's inside the head so Agya chakra should be inside the forehead.

So where exactly Agya chakra is located? At the forehead or inside the forehead?

Comment: its 'exact' location is in the fine body, not the gross body